# android client side doesnt read after a while

Tags: java, android, sockets, google-api, speech-recognition

It's my first question in here. I hope i can find answer. Subject is that, i have server (arduino). it send and receive data.it send data when take a data from client side(android). Android side is send data when push button. Also android has use Speech to Text (google API).So when we push button or use speechrecognation, client side send a data.But it reads socket continuously. I have two kind android device. One device work well about data receiving but it is not good about speechrecognation. One device very well about voice but after a while socket is happened useless. We must push reset button on arduino and reset android app. (My first android device version is 5.1.1 second is 6.0). Sorry for my english. I hope i can tell my problem :)

```
.
.
.
public void senddata(String asd){

    try {

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(asd);
        out.flush();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 .
 .
 .

  class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        BufferedReader inStream = null;


        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            //socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
            // Get the input and output streams
             inStream = new BufferedReader(new
                     InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


            // Confirm that the socket opened


            // Read messages in a loop until disconnected

            while( true){
                String msg= inStream.readLine();
                Log.e("GELENLER::::",msg);
                gelenkomut=msg;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        gelenparse(gelenkomut);

                    }
                });

                // Send it to the UI thread
            }


        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                inStream.reset();
                inStream.
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should better explain what data the arduino is sending.

Comment: `senddata(String asd){`. Please explain for what you use this function?

Comment: arduino send String line (it has 5 comments. I check comments with use contains. ) for example string is "t1#25-t2#12-t3#as-t4#22" I write my texts respectively 25 12 as 22.

Comment: I send data when push button or use speechrecognation. when i do one of them, i call this function.

Comment: Although you did not post Arduino code -so we cannot see what you do- you said that the Arduino sends lines. So the string you posted ends with  "\n". Please confirm.

Comment: senddata() does not send lines. What are you doing at Arduino side? Reading lines or what?

Comment: `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);`.  !!!!!!!!!!!! For every button press or little text you have this statement. Wrong. Take it out of the function. You can execute this statement only once in the lifetime of the socket.

Comment: arduio send function code is :   esp8266.write("AT+CIPSEND=0,21\r\n");
while(esp8266.find(">")==0);
delay(5);
esp8266.write(QO*FC*HC*IO*FF5*FZ18\n);
delay(5);

Comment: Okey you are right about that. but i don't think problem that caused it. because when i dont push anything, socket broken too. So i think problem is on receive data. but i don't know where :)